# Is it possible to get MySQL to compute values from two different rows from the same table?

Tags: php, mysql

So I am writing a script which takes lots of data in the form of market orders and price histories, and computes their profitability and markup etc.

Now, I have this running perfectly fine in PHP but it is quite slow. I thought maybe it would be possible for MySQL to sort through the data and then only return the correct data, rather than return everything and let the script go through it. The script is a php page so as you can imagine, the quicker the better.

I've been trying all sorts, but nothing seems to be working. If anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them.

The marketinfo table has these columns:
**Id, ItemId, StationId, BuyPrice, SellPrice, AvailableVolume, LastUpdated**

The pricehistory table has these columns:
**Id, ItemId, RegionId, HistoryDate, Volume**

There are rows identified by ItemId in each of these tables, for marketinfo there are two rows, one for station A and one for station B. There is also a row in the pricehistory table for each ItemId. We find that row by using a cross reference table stations which points StationId to a RegionId etc.

The data we use from pricehistory is simply AVG(Volume) where ItemId=x and RegionId=y. There are two rows per item in marketinfo that are used. Buy point and sell point.

If we call the buy data row B and the sell data row S, what I need to is say select all items where (S.SellPrice / B.BuyPrice) > 1.20, and then return SellPrice, AvailableVolume, LastUpdated from S, BuyPrice from B, then use the ItemId & StationId to join it to pricehistory and get AVG(Volume) and then also join that to an items database on ItemId to get ItemName.

As you can tell, this is one big ass MySQL query. The trouble I am having is selecting two rows from the same table.

**TLDR:** I need something like:

```
select * from (  
  select * from marketinfo where StationId='1' as B  
  AND  
  select * from marketinfo where StationId='2' as S  
)  
where (S.SellPrice / B.BuyPrice) > 1.20
```

I know the above isn't valid SQL but that is the *kind* of thing I'm after.

Is this possible? Or more over, how is this possible?

Thank you so much for reaching the end of this long and confusing post.

Edit: I've come up with something like.. I think it works..

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, (a.SellPrice / b.BuyPrice) FROM marketinfo a, marketinfo b 
WHERE (a.SellPrice / b.BuyPrice) > 1.60 AND a.ItemId = b.ItemId
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

`SELECT * FROM marketinfo AS t1 INNER JOIN marketinfo AS t2 ON t1.ItemId = t2.ItemId AND t2.StationId = 2 WHERE t1.StationId = 1 HAVING t2.SellPrice / t1.BuyPrice > 1.20`

Comment: This is working but I am running into a new issue now. I have this (http://pastebin.com/CErdc9iT) but I need to get only the most recent row from pricehistory, sort of like an ORDER BY DateField DESC LIMIT 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking back on this now that I'm more awake, the "HAVING" clause could probably just be an additional "WHERE" clause. Also, I don't know enough about the database structure or what sort of result set you need to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this maybe?

```
select * from 
(select * from marketinfo where StationId='1') as B,  
(select * from marketinfo where StationId='2') as S
where (S.SellPrice / B.BuyPrice) > 1.20
```

Comment: This does not appear to work, not sure why but causes phpmyadmin to crash actually! Strange, but thanks!

Comment: Hmm, weird, I'm not able to produce the error you describe. But I read from your original post you have already got something that works so its probably not worth bothering. :)